# Why do I always get empty list thing to select a tag or css property by using Python?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I just started studying Python, requests and BeautifulSoup.

I'm using VSCode and Python version is 3.10.8

I want to get HTML code using a 'taw' tag in google. but I can't get it. the result keeps getting an empty list.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=프로그래밍+공부&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8'

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

find = soup.select('#taw')

print(find)
```

and here's HTML code that I tried to get 'taw' tag

[image]

sorry for using image instead of codes.

Taw tag contains Google's ad site and I want to scrap this tag. I tried other CSS properties and tags, but the empty list keeps showing up as a result. I tried soup.find, but I got 'None'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For various possible reasons, you don't always get the exact same html via python's `requests.get` as what you see in your browser. Sometimes it's because of blockers or JavaScript loading, but for this specific page and element, it's just that google will format the response a bot differently based on the source of the request. Try adding some headers

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=프로그래밍+공부&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
reqErr = response.raise_for_status() # just a good habit to check
if reqErr: print(f'!"{reqErr}" - while getting ', url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

find = soup.select('#taw')
if not find: ## save html to check [IN AN EDITOR, NOT a browser] if expected elements are missing
    hfn = 'x.html'
    with open(hfn, 'wb') as f: f.write(response.content)
    print(f'saved html to  "{hfn}"')

print(find)
```

<sub>The `reqErr` and *`if not find....`* parts are just to help understand why in case you don't get the expected results. They're helpful for debugging in general for requests+bs4 scraping attempts.</sub>

The printed output I got with the code above was:

```html
[<div id="taw"><div data-ved="2ahUKEwjvjrj04ev7AhV3LDQIHaXeDCkQL3oECAcQAg" id="oFNiHe"></div><div id="tvcap"></div></div>]
```

Comment: thanks to reply to my question! I can't fully understand the code you answered yet, but I will study hard and understand it perfectly